# Setting visibility of button when back pressed from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity where the user enters some data and submits it via a submit button, that same activity also has some more buttons which lead to fragments.

When I click on the fragments, the submit button of the activity overlaps the UI of the fragment, so in the calling code of fragments I set the visibility of that submit button as invisible but when back pressed from fragment then also that submit button is invisible.

I want the submit button to be visible when activity is being displayed and invisible when the fragments are being displayed.

Comment: try changing fragment background colour to white.

Comment: @AIK nop, still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your fragment on button click,

```
loginSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.addToBackStack("LayoutFragment");
            ft.add(R.id.framelayoutfaqs, new LayoutFragment());
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        loginSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**NOTE :** make sure you import same `Fragment` class which you used to create `YourFragment`. Also choose `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()` accordingly.

Comment: What is this YourFragment after instanceof?

Comment: Name of your fragment class.

Comment: No, still the button is visible on fragment :/

Comment: Sure, adding it.

Comment: I tried, still the same, I have added the code, please have a look

Comment: use `findFragmentById(R.id.framelayoutfaqs)` not `faqsContainer`.

Comment: 1. Initially Submit button is visible.
2. When clicked on FAQs Button the fragment layout has Submit button overlapping it.
3. When back pressed and activity reached Submit button is invisible.
4. Again a back press leads to visibility of Submit button and get back to previous activity.

Comment: You only need to use if loop in `onBackPressed()`. Still not solved add Activity & Fragment class.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: In updated answer there is only if loop, no need to set else portion.

Comment: By using only 'if', all 1-3 points of my previous comment are taking place, not 4th, it directly just gets back to previous activity

Comment: Please check updated answer, I created demo & this is working fine.

Comment: my loginSubmit goes to next activity not fragment

Comment: It shows that what to do on loginSubmit button click, you can do this in Activity, no need to add it in fragment class.

Comment: Sorry mate, still the button is visible/overlapping the fragment.

Comment: You need to set `loginSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);` on loginSubmit clicked.

Comment: Yes I did that, still was the same

Comment: Okay got it, instead of placing loginSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE); on loginSubmit clicked, I placed it in the fragment call, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much! You too! By the way can you explain how your code of onBackPressed() works?

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in 0nBackPressed() method of Activity class .

Comment: Can you tell how?

Comment: @Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
    } else { 
        this.finish(); 
    }
}

Comment: Your code for adding fragment to backstack should be like:

getFragmentManager() .beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.content_frame, Entry_Account.newInstance(), Entry_Account.TAG).addToBackStack("Some string") .commit();
Then On Activity's onBackPressed method,use this snippet:

@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
if(getFramentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
      // popback statck.
}
 else{
     // finish your activity.
 }
}

Answer (score -1):

Make the button invisible in either of `onCreate`, `onActivityCreated` or `onAttach` methods of your fragment and make it visible in `onDetach` method of your fragment.

Comment: This is infeasible while working with External Fragment.

Comment: As per the situation, you can say that the fragment isn't external in this particular scenario. So I would prefer this instead of unnecessarily overriding my onBackPressed method.

Comment: How could you be sure by reading the question that is can't be external fragment?

Comment: @RachitSeksaria In my fragment code, I made reference to the activity's button and then set its visibility as invisible but then error "NullPointerException"showed up on the line where i set it as invisible.

Comment: @RachitSeksaria Hey it worked! Thank you so much! :)